# Plotly - Values of dict object not JSON serializable for timestamp?

Tags: python, plotly

I'm trying to use plotly to create a scatter plot, but it seems like my timestamp is not JSON serializable? This is the error I'm getting:

```
TypeError <built-in method values of dict object at 0x7f6f3d8ac910> is not JSON serializable
```

And this is the code I currently have:

```
df = datasets[3]

#New column with hour rounded
df['hour'] = df['p_time'].dt.floor('h')

hour_counts = {}
for hour in df['hour']:
    if hour in hour_counts:
        hour_counts[hour] = hour_counts[hour] + 1
    else:
        hour_counts[hour] = 1 

print hour_counts

count = Scatter(
    x= hour_counts.keys,
    y= hour_counts.values,
    name = "Number of Riders",
    line = dict(color = '#17BECF'),
    opacity = 0.8)

data = [count]

layout = dict(
    title='Time Series with Rangeslider',
    xaxis=dict(
        rangeselector=dict(
            buttons=list([
                dict(count=1,
                     label='1d',
                     step='day',
                     stepmode='backward'),
                dict(count=6,
                     label='6d',
                     step='day',
                     stepmode='backward'),
                dict(step='all')
            ])
        ),
        rangeslider=dict(),
        type='date'
    )
)

fig = dict(data=data, layout=layout)
iplot(fig)
```

Can anyone provide some insight? Apologies if this is a stupid question. I'm very new to python. Thank you!

Comment: Well, you haven't really given us much to go on here, but I think you need to use `df['hour'] = df['hour'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')` or something similar before you send it to be plotted. Obviously, I don't know what format you want your datetimes to be, that's an example. Does that work? Even regular python datetimes cannot be serialized to json without some intervention.

Comment: It seems like the times are showing up as this type of variable - <type 'builtin_function_or_method'> - rather than a timestamp when I add them to a dictionary. Tried to use df['hour'] = pd.to_datetime(df['hour']) to convert the values to timestamps but when I put the values inside the dictionary, it seems like the type changes? Used print type(hour_counts.keys) to look it up and I get <type 'builtin_function_or_method'> as a result. Is there a way to use the to_datetime function on the keys in a dictionary? Sorry if that doesn't make any sense! Many thanks.

Comment: You should have included the traceback in the question. `x= hour_counts.keys` and `y= hour_counts.values` are just binding the methods to those names, not _calling_ them. Try changing to `x= hour_counts.keys()` and `y= hour_counts.values()`

Comment: Tried the fix and I don't get an error anymore, but it seems like I get no output? And when I try to `print data` it seems like I get no output as well after I put my x and y values into the scatter function. I printed my dictionary as well as `hour_counts.keys` and `hour_counts.values` to make sure nothing was going wrong there and it seems that the lists populate correctly.